# How to compile a Python script using Tensorflow to a .exe file to be used on a computer without Python and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, compilation, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I have created a working Python script containing a Tensorflow model that can identify images. I would like to compile this script in to some form of .exe file that can be used on computers without Python and Tensorflow installed. I would appreciate any help in this regard. Which programs and versions to use, how to use them and may be some code lines to guide me.
I have without luck tried py2exe, pyinstaller and cx_freeze. Currently I am using Tensorflow 2.0 and Python 3.7.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python cannot be compiled. You can achieve a similar behavior with `Cython`, but for a good result you have to put type annotations. The best way to bring a Python script to other computers is to encapsulate it with a minimal interpreter like the tools you mentioned do.

Comment: I've don't have experience with this, but this thread might help https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/664lfp/how_do_you_create_a_selfcontained_deeplearning/ ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I see that the problem is a little more complicated than first envisioned.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you didnt have any luck with cx_Freeze but give it a try

I made a guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255467/how-to-convert-a-python-project-into-an-executable-file-with-all-additional-scri/62272817#62272817) answering someone elses question