# How to convert a python project into an executable file with all additional scripts?

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I know there have been a bunch of questions already asked regarding this but none of them really helped me. Let me explain the whole project scenario so that I provide a better clarity to my problem. The directory structure is somewhat like this shown below:

Project Directory Layout

[image]

I need to convert this whole GUI based project (The main file is using Tkinter module to create GUI) into main.exe which I can share with others while making sure that all the additional files work exactly the same way it is working now when I run this main.py via Command Prompt. When I use this command with pyinstaller -

```
"pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py"
```

It creates main.exe which shows "Failed to execute script" on running. Please provide me a detailed explanation on what should I do to achieve what I have stated above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to add those directories using `Tree(...)` in the SPEC file.  See [document](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#the-tree-class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyinstaller uses a few dirty tricks to compress a bunch of files into one

I recommend using cx_Freeze instead along with inno setup installer maker

do `pip install cx_Freeze` to install that and go [here](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) for inno setup

then copy the following into a file named setup.py in the same folder as your project

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name = "YOUR APP NAME" ,
      version = "1.0.0" ,
      description = "DESCRIPTION" ,
      executables = [Executable("PYTHON FILE", base = "Win32GUI")]
)
```

lastly run `python setup.py build`

if you want as onefile download this file [here](https://gofile.io/d/h6bQbu)

just edit the file a bit and use inno compiler to make into installer

Comment: Thanks for telling me about cx_freeze. It certainly took me a while to fix all the bugs and understand it a bit but it was totally worth it. Thanks a ton for your much needed help. :D

Comment: That download link seem dead. Please provide the code here, if not too long or a better source, like your own gist, for example.

Comment: Here's [inno setup on github](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc).

Comment: I am getting this error when I try "python setup.py build" on a script with tensorflow.
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose our project has the following structure.

```sh
MyApp
  |-models
  |  |-login.kv
  |-data
  |  |-words.json
  |  |-audio.tar.gz
  |-fonts
  |  |-FredokaOne.ttf
  |-images
  |  |-gb.pngsound.png
  |  |-icon.ico
  |-main.py
  |-main.kv
  |-draw.py
  |-image.py
```

and depends on the following packages:

```sh
- kivy
- kivymd
- ffpyplayer
- gtts
```

1. First things first is to install `cx_Freeze`.

```sh
pip install cx_Freeze
```

2. Copy the following into a file named `setup.py` in the same folder as your project.

```py
# https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html

import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = []

# Include your files and folders
includefiles = ['models/','data/','fonts/','images/','main.kv','draw.py','image.py']

# Exclude unnecessary packages
excludes = ['cx_Freeze','pydoc_data','setuptools','distutils','tkinter']

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but some modules need help.
packages = ['kivy','kivymd', 'ffpyplayer','gtts']    

base = None
shortcutName = None
shortcutDir = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
    shortcutName='My App'
    shortcutDir="DesktopFolder"

setup(
    name = 'MyApp',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Sample python app',
    author = 'your name',
    author_email = '',
    options = {'build_exe': {
        'includes': includes,
        'excludes': excludes,
        'packages': packages,
        'include_files': includefiles}
        }, 
    executables = [Executable('main.py', 
    base = base, # "Console", base, # None
    icon='images/icon.ico', 
    shortcutName = shortcutName, 
    shortcutDir = shortcutDir)]
)
```

3. Lastly run.

```
python setup.py build
```

This command will create a subdirectory called `build` with a further subdirectory starting with the letters `exe.` and ending with the typical identifier for the platform that distutils uses. This allows for multiple platforms to be built without conflicts.

On Windows, you can build a simple installer containing all the files cx_Freeze includes for your application, by running the setup script as:

```sh
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

#### Cx_freeze references

- [Doc](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze)
- [Git Hub](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html)